# Listbox seen as Nonetype, why?

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, nonetype

```
self.__tracksListBox = Listbox(self.__master, width=100, height=25).grid(row=0, column=1,
                                                                           rowspan=4)
```

I'm trying to display options in a Listbox, but the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\aawiesinger5000\Desktop\CS 110 Final Project\layoutGUI.py", line 213, in showTracks
    self.__tracksListBox.insert(END, titleStr)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

when I try to use the list box like this:

```
if tracks:
            titleStr = ""
            for track in tracks:
                titleStr += track + "\n"
            self.__tracksListBox.insert(END, titleStr)
```

Does anyone know why?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) method does not return; implicitly return `None`.

Separate the following statement into two statements:

```
self.__tracksListBox = Listbox(self.__master, width=100, height=25).grid(row=0, column=1,
                                                                           rowspan=4)
```

like:

```
self.__tracksListBox = Listbox(self.__master, width=100, height=25)
self.__tracksListBox.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4)
```